# Can I select a list to search by user inputted text such that the inputted text matches the variable name of the list

Tags: python, list

This is part of a "playground" program where I try out things as I am learning python, for data its all ad&d related because reasons.

Anyway I was looking for a way to improve code efficacy.

So I have these 4 lists (I realise a data frame would be more efficient and that will be the next bit of code I try)

```
rouge = [20, 20, 19, 19, 18, 18, 17, 17, 16,
         16, 15, 15, 14, 14, 13, 13, 12, 12, 11, 11]
priest = [20, 20, 20, 18, 18, 18, 16, 16, 16,
          14, 14, 14, 12, 12, 12, 10, 10, 10, 8, 8]
warrior = [20, 19, 18, 17, 16, 15, 14, 13,
           12, 11, 10, 9, 8, 7, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1]
wizard = [20, 20, 20, 19, 19, 19, 18, 18, 18,
          17, 17, 17, 16, 16, 16, 15, 15, 15, 14, 14]
```

Anyway my old, working, code would retrieve the THAC0 values, aka those in lists, based upon index value which the player would enter as "playerlevel".

I sought to improve it with this code (the old code is in a separate file and does not effect this, it worked as a bunch of nested if statements and took over 60 lines of code).

```
    playerclass = input("Please enter a class type: ").strip().lower()
    if not playerclass in possibleclasses: #a comparison to a list to prevent input of invalid data
        playerclass = input("Enter a valid class type: ").strip().lower()
    playerlevelinput = input("Please enter level: ")
    while not playerlevelinput.isdigit():
        playerlevelinput = input(
            "Error. Please input a level, a level must be an integer value: ")
    playerlevel = (int(playerlevelinput) - 1) #-1 due to index start at 0
    THAC0 = playerclass[playerlevel]  *# doesn't work*
    print(f"The character's THAC0 is {THAC0}")
    wait = input("Press any key to continue")
```

Now this part doesn't work, however I hope its clear what I tried to do, I wish to search in the list for which the variable name (of the list) matches the playerclass input variable; e.g, search in the *wizard* list if the input is "wizard".

I receive "IndexError: string index out of range" when I try this.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a dictionary where keys are names of classes and the values are the lists:

```py
# wizard, priest, warrior, rouge are the four lists from the question:
classes_dct = {
    "wizard": wizard,
    "priest": priest,
    "warrior": warrior,
    "rouge": rouge,
}


playerclass = input("Please enter a class type: ")
playerlevel = int(input("Please enter level: ")) - 1

if playerclass in classes_dct and playerlevel < len(classes_dct[playerclass]):
    THAC0 = classes_dct[playerclass][playerlevel]
    print(f"The character's THAC0 is {THAC0}")
else:
    print("Incorrect input.")
```

Prints (for example):

```
Please enter a class type: wizard
Please enter level: 3
The character's THAC0 is 20
```

Comment: So you use a dictionary to assign strings to variables such that any string which matches the variable name (or whatever you set it as in the dictionary) is referred to as that variable?

This works brilliantly